# Rails 4.0 - Nested Attributes with Devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I am using Rails 4.0 and would like to use Devise for my sign-up/sign-out/etc.

However, on my sign-up page I would like to have fields not only from the user model that devise creates but also another model that users have a relationship with (organizations in this case).

I have setup associations on the models for user and organization like so:

```
user.rb 

has_one :organization

accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization

organization.rb

belongs_to :user
```

Any ideas on how to make this happen? I tried overriding the registration controller for devise but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the views and insert a `fields_for` block for that `:organization` association. Run `rails generate devise:views` and look for the new view files in your `app/views/devise` directory.